# Instance of jPlayer in modal window does not stop when closed

Tags: jquery, jplayer

I have an instance of jPlayer inside of a jQuery modal window.  It works great except the fact that when I close the window the player keeps playing. I am able to capture the window's close event, but for some reason not the player itself.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is some of my code:

```
//Modal Dialog
$(function () {
    var dHeight = $("#dialog-modal").data("mdheight"),
        dWidth = $("#dialog-modal").data("mdwidth");
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: dHeight,
        width: dWidth,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true
    });
    $("#modal-opener").click(function () {
        $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
        return false;
    });
    //Capture dialog closing
    $("#dialog-modal").live("dialogclose", function (event) {
        $("#jquery_jplayer_1'").jPlayer("destroy");
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    new jPlayerPlaylist({
        jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
    }, [{
        title: "Amazing Grace",
        mp3: "AmazingGrace.mp3",
        oga: "AmazingGrace.ogg"
    }
    });
```

Comment: why not make a stop at "dialog before close" event

Answer (score 0):

I got it working and the fix is here on another forum: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jplayer/NSzSXe5nPbE